# Show that the following subspace is two dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

L= span {$e_{1}$, $e_{2}$} and K = span{$f_{1}$ $f_{2}$} are two disjoint subspaces in $\mathbb R^4$. Every 2x2 matrix A represents a linear transformation from L to K such as

A($x_{1}$$e_{1}$+$x_{2}$$e_{2}$)= $y_{1}$$f_{1}$+$y_{2}$$f_{2}$ where [$y_{1}$ $y_{2}$]$^{T}$=$\textbf{A}$ [$x_{1}$ $x_{2}$]$^{T}$

Show that the subspace $W_{A}$ of all vectors $x_{1}$$e_{1}$+$x_{2}$$e_{2}$+A($x_{1}$$e_{1}$+$x_{2}$$e_{2}$) such that $x_{1}$, $x_{2}$ $\in$ $\mathbb R^2$ is a two dimenisonal subspace in $\mathbb R^4$

The solution defines the transformation, ($x_{1}$, $x_{2}$) $\rightarrow$ $x_{1}$$e_{1}$+$x_{2}$$e_{2}$+A($x_{1}$$e_{1}$+$x_{2}$$e_{2}$), and shows that the null space is trivial, making the image space ($W_{A}$) two dimensional. However my attempt was to rewrite all the vectors in the
subspace $W_{A}$ to $x_{1}$$e_{1}$+$x_{2}$$e_{2}$+$y_{1}$$f_{1}$+$y_{2}$$f_{2}$, which is a linear combination of 4 linearly independent vectors (as L and K are disjoint subspaces), how can the subspace then be 2 dimensional?

$\textbf{EDIT}$: Why does that fact that the kernel of the transformation ($x_{1}$, $x_{2}$) $\rightarrow$ $x_{1}$$e_{1}$+$x_{2}$$e_{2}$+A($x_{1}$$e_{1}$+$x_{2}$$e_{2}$) is trivial, imply that the dimension of $W_{A}$ is 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space $W_A$ is a subspace of$$W=\{x_1e_1+x_2e_2+y_1f_1+y_2f_2\mid x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2\in\Bbb R^4\}$$and this space is indeed $4$-dimensional. But $W_A\varsubsetneq W$, and so $\dim W_A<4$. And we have $W_A\varsubsetneq W$ because, when $x_1e_1+x_2e_2+y_1f_1+y_2f_2\in W_A$, the numbers $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_1$, and $y_2$ cannot be just *any* numbers; we must have$$\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{bmatrix}=A.\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not quite sure I understand how $$\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{bmatrix}=A.\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}.$$ restricts the subspace $W_{A}$ to not be 4 dimensional? As A($x_{1}$$e_{1}$+$x_{2}$$e_{2}$)= $y_{1}$$f_{1}$+$y_{2}$$f_{2}$, why can't I rewrite the vectors in $W_{A}$ using the definition?

Comment: Suppose, say, that $A=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. Then a generic element of $W_A$ is of the form $x_1e_1+x_2e_2+y_1f_1+y_2f_2$, with$$\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\y_2\end{bmatrix}=A.\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}.$$That is, a generic element of $W_A$ is of the form $x_1e_1+x_2e_2+x_1f_1+x_2f_2$ and therefore it depends only on **two** parameters $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: Okey, thank you. The generic element of $W_{A}$ is a linear combination of 4 linearly independent vectors, so why is $W_{A}$  not 4 dimensional? Why does the fact that is only depends on two parameters determine its dimension

Comment: Because the dimension is precisely the number of parameters that you need to describe the whole space. On the other and, while it is indeed true that $W_A$ is a set of linear combinations of $4$ linearly independent vectors, it does not consist of **all** such linear combinations. The space of all such linear combinations is indeed $4$-dimensional, but its subspaces don't have to be.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I think I finally understand now. Could I just quickly ask, why the fact that the kernel of the transformation ($x_{1}$, $x_{2}$) $\rightarrow$ $x_{1}$$e_{1}$+$x_{2}$$e_{2}$+A($x_{1}$$e_{1}$+$x_{2}$$e_{2}$) is zero implies that $W_{A}$ is two dimensional, I know that A is a 2x2 matrix, but the linear transformation mentioned above is not defined by A.

Comment: By the rank-nullity theorem, the dimension of the image of that linear transformation (that is, $\dim W_A$) is the dimension of the domain (which is $2$) minus the dimension of the kernel (which is $0$).

Comment: right but the transformation ($x_{1}$, $x_{2}$) $\rightarrow$ $x_{1}$$e_{1}$+$x_{2}$$e_{2}$+A($x_{1}$$e_{1}$+$x_{2}$$e_{2}$) does not have A as its standardmatrix, as that would be ($x_{1}$, $x_{2}$) $\rightarrow$ A($x_{1}$$e_{1}$+$x_{2}$$e_{2}$)  without the ($x_{1}$, $x_{2}$) added to it?

Comment: I never claimed it did. Nevertheless, its image is $W_A$, its kernel is $\{0\}$, and its domain is $\Bbb R^2$. And that's all you need to know in order to be able to apply the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: Thank you for all the help!